# Редактировать MX запись через консоль

Tags: ispmanager, centos6

День добрый. Купил vps на reg.ru, подключил ispmanager 5, хотел настроить записи и подключить яндекс почту.

Прописал MX записи, проверил через яндекс, возвращает mail.mysite.ru вместо mx.yandex.net.
Через консоль залез в /var/named/domains/mysite.ru" пишет, что  MX =  mx.yandex.net.
В то же время, dig mysite.ru MX возвращает 2 записи mail.caracall.ru.
Подскажите,  как и где  это поправить.

Спасибо.

Comment: `dig -t NS mysite.ru` в студию для начала

Comment: ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.1 <<>> -t NS caracall.ru
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59406
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;caracall.ru.                   IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
caracall.ru.            3599    IN      NS      ns5.hosting.reg.ru.
caracall.ru.            3599    IN      NS      ns6.hosting.reg.ru.

;; Query time: 47 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 30 22:03:18 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77

Comment: Теперь смотрите `dig MX caracall.ru @ns5.hosting.reg.ru`. У вас NS сервер ns5.hosting.reg.ru все верно? Это авторитативный сервер, с которого информация распространяется по интернету. Если без собачки - то получите от своего хостера, а не с авторитативного. Хостеры, как и положено, кешируют записи

Comment: ;; ANSWER SECTION:
caracall.ru.            3600    IN      MX      10 mail.caracall.ru.
caracall.ru.            3600    IN      MX      20 mail.caracall.ru.     Все верно.

Comment: `/var/named/domains/mysite.ru`, который правите, находится на `ns5.hosting.reg.ru`? Дико сомневаюсь.

Comment: Если вас смущает mysite.ru, то это я по привычке привычке написал. На самом деле сайт caracall.ru. отвечая на ваш вопрос, в dns хостинга прописаны s5.hosting.reg.ru; ns6.hosting.reg.ru

Comment: `/var/named/domains/caracall.ru` на `ns5.hosting.reg.ru`? полагаю, что нет. это значит у вас поднят свой DNS, на caracall.ru. так и есть `dig MX caracall.ru @caracall.ru`. значит хостер должен делегировать зону `caracall.ru` на вас (в настройках своего DNS сервера), но он похоже этого не сделал, или я не догоняю

Comment: обычно VDS хостеры предлагают отдельную панель, где можно управлять DNS по своим серверам, как раз тем самым `ns5.hosting.reg.ru`. а разворачивать DNS на своем сервере, чтобы хостер заделегировал на вас, "внутри", причем авторитативный сервер, это извращение. написал сумбурно, надеюсь поймете